# No stylesheet is working expect menu in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, stylesheet

I installed a new theme and was editing menu and then site broke. Only menu css is fine and after that in place of image i see array codes and no css is working. 
Css is not working for any theme. 
Please find the css and help [image: error]

Comment: this not related to css you have some page builder was included in your old theme and your pages was built  by that builder , when you changed them theme that builder is not active anymore that's why you see your site like this

Comment: so how can i solve the issue ???

Comment: go back to your old theme or rewrite your pages with your new them

Comment: but no other theme is working.. all themes are looking like this now...I even re installed the theme which i was working on.. But that too didn't worked

Comment: in this case its a plugin not them check if you have any deactivated  plugin builder

Comment: Check your (inactive) plug-ins. This seems like a case of a visual composure/editor plug-in not being active and/or installed. It could be bundled with the previously used them you had active before installing the new one.

Comment: yes got it... some plugins got deactived.. thanks @imrafaelhi & kashalo

Answer (score 0):

Edit it with theme editor. go to wp-admin ==> themes == edit there have all css files and php files